# How to make a flow sleep until a condition is satisfied in Mulesoft

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Am having 5 batch process in my flow and the batch process are running async I need to wait untill all the batch processs are over but once batch execute component is executed the payload moves to the next component where it requires a result from batch and it fails.How can I make it wait untill all the batch process are executed

Answer (score 0):

@Satheesh,

Use a sessionVars or set static variable where you will use that as a flag or increment that. Then use an expression-filter where you will check if it already process all the batch processes.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/filters